# submit form even is invalid c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem when click on submit button. the data still insert into database even though there is an invalid data.

```
public partial class surveyCreate : System.Web.UI.Page
{
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
private string lblTextMessage;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnSubmitSurvey.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return PostPage();");

    List<string> keys = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(key => key.Contains("txtDynamic")).ToList();
    int i = 1;
    foreach (string key in keys)
    {
        this.CreateTextBox("txtDynamic" + i);
        i++;
    }


    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        int a_unit = 0;
        string username = (string)Session["Username"];
        string query5 = "SELECT * FROM tblAdmin WHERE a_uname='" + username + "'";
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand(query5, con);
        SqlDataReader dr5 = cmd5.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr5.Read())
        {
            a_unit = Convert.ToInt32(dr5["a_unit"]);

        }

        dr5.Close();
        con.Close();

        string queryA = "";
        string queryB = "";
        string queryC = "";

        queryA = "SELECT * FROM tblUnit WHERE u_master = " + a_unit;
        queryB = "SELECT * FROM tblProject ";
        queryC = "SELECT * FROM tblSurveyTemplate where st_template = " + a_unit;

        BindDropDownList(ddlunit, queryA, "u_name", "u_id", "SELECT UNIT");
        //BindDropDownList(project, queryB, "pro_name", "pro_id", "SELECT PROJECT");
        BindDropDownList(ddlTemplate, queryC, "st_name", "st_id", "SELECT TEMPLATE");

        ddlproject.Enabled = false;


    }
}


private void BindDropDownList(DropDownList ddl, string query, string text, string value, string defaultText)
{

    // string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
    {

        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            ddl.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddl.DataTextField = text;
            ddl.DataValueField = value;
            ddl.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(defaultText, "0"));
}

protected void unit_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlproject.Enabled = true;

    int u_id = int.Parse(ddlunit.SelectedItem.Value);

    string query = "Select pro_id, pro_name from tblProject WHERE u_id=" + u_id;
    BindDropDownList(ddlproject, query, "pro_name", "pro_id", "SELECT PROJECT");

}

protected void ddlTemplate_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int st_id = int.Parse(ddlTemplate.SelectedItem.Value);

    SqlDataSourceQuestions.SelectCommand = "SELECT sq_id, sq_question FROM tblSurveyQuestions WHERE st_id=" + st_id;

    string query = "SELECT * FROM tblSurveyTemplate WHERE st_id=" + st_id;

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        LabelComment.Text = dr["st_comment"].ToString();
        LabelIntro.Text = dr["st_intro"].ToString();
    }

    dr.Close();
    con.Close();

    if (st_id != 0)
        PanelA.Visible = true;
    else
        PanelA.Visible = false;
}

/**
protected void project_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    project.Enabled = true;
    project.Items.Clear();
    project.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("SELECT PROJECT", "0"));

    int unitId = int.Parse(unit.SelectedItem.Value);
    if (unitId > 0)
    {
        string query = string.Format("Select pro_id, pro_name from tblProject where pro_id = {0} ", unitId);
        BindDropDownList(project, query, "pro_name", "pro_id", "SELECT PROJECT");
        project.Enabled = true;
    }

}

static int i = 0;

protected void btn_addp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int j = 0;
    i++;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Width = 350;
        tb.ID = "MP" + j.ToString();

        ph.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
}
*/

protected void btn_addp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int index = pnlTB.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().Count + 1;
    this.CreateTextBox("txtDynamic" + index);
}


private void CreateTextBox(string id)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = id;
    tb.Width = 350;
    pnlTB.Controls.Add(tb);

    Literal lt = new Literal();
    lt.Text = "<div style=height:3px ></div>";
    pnlTB.Controls.Add(lt);
    pnlTB.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div style=height:3px ></div>"));

}

protected void GetTextBoxValues(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

//duplicate email
protected void cv_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    //TextBox[] participant = { participant1, participant2, participant3 };
    //if (participant1.Text == participant2.Text || participant2.Text == participant3.Text || participant1.Text == participant3.Text)
    //{
    //    cvSubmit.ErrorMessage = "* Duplicate email! Please enter different email. ";
    //    cvSubmit.Focus();

    //    e.IsValid = false;
    //}

}
```

here is the code for submit

```
protected void btnSubmitSurvey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a_id = "";
    string username = (string)Session["Username"];
    string query4 = "SELECT * FROM tblAdmin WHERE a_uname='" + username + "'";
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand(query4, con);
    SqlDataReader dr4 = cmd4.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr4.Read())
    {
        a_id = dr4["a_id"].ToString();

    }

    dr4.Close();
    con.Close();

    if (Page.IsValid)
    {

            con.Open();

            string query = "CreateSurvey";
            string query1 = "ListParticipant";
            int surveyID;
            DateTime date_now = DateTime.Now;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sd_id", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "sd_id");
            cmd.Parameters["@sd_id"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sd_title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtTitle.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sd_unit", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ddlunit.SelectedValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sd_project", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ddlproject.SelectedValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sd_year", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtYear.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@st_id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ddlTemplate.SelectedValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sd_datecreated", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date_now;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sd_createdBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = a_id;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            surveyID = (int)cmd.Parameters["@sd_id"].Value;

        //validate email
       bool email = Regex.IsMatch(participant.Text.Trim(), "\\w+([-+.']\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*");

        if (!email)
        {
            lbl2.Text = "Invalid email address";
            return;
            }
            else
            {
            lbl2.Text = "";
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);

            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@sp_email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = participant.Text;

            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@sd_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = surveyID;

            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }   


        foreach (TextBox textBox in pnlTB.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            if (textBox.Text != "")
            {
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@sp_email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox.Text;
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@sd_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = surveyID;
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }


        string message = "Your survey details has been saved.";
        string url = "surveyConfirm.aspx?surveyId=" + surveyID;
        string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
        script += message;
        script += "');";
        script += "window.location = '";
        script += url;
        script += "'; }";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Redirect", script, true);

        con.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        lbl2.Text = "Fill up the information required";            
    }
}
}
```

someone please help me to solve this problem. thank you

Comment: What do you mean "there is an invalid data" ??  You didn't include the code for any of your validators.

Comment: What data is invalid, and what is it about the data that makes it invalid?